# Help with set functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = B = N$, where N is the set of natural numbers.
Define $f:A \to B$ by $f(a)=2a$ and define $g:B\to A$ by $g(b)=3b$

Find $g^{-1}(\{2,4,6\})$.

Find $g^{-1} (\{2,4\})$

My trouble here is would $g^{-1}$ just be f?

Also an explanation of what the difference between $f(g(3))$ and $f(g(\{3\}))$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more formal definition (not just specific to your example is):

Given a function $f: X \to Y$, with $A \subseteq Y$, the preimage is defined as:
$$
f^{-1}(A) = \{x\in X| f(x) \in A\}
$$
For the first example:

What values could we plug in to $g$ to get $\{2,4,6\}$?

---

There is no real difference between $f(g(3))$ and $f(g(\{3\}))$.
The former is just short hand for the latter.

Comment: "The former is just short hand for the latter." $\leftarrow$ This isn't true; $f(g(3))$ is a number whereas $f(g(\{3\}))$ is a set.

Comment: A function is a set of input to a set of output yes?

Comment: Sure, depending on your formalism, but that's not the point: here, $f(g(3))=18$, which is a natural number, but $f(g(\{3\}))=\{18\}$, which is a set containing a natural number.

Comment: Yes, if it was rational or real numbers that would be the answer. The only one that works is 2, so I think your answer would be {2}

Comment: Thank you I think that is where my confusion was coming from.

Answer (score 0):

${g^{ - 1}} \ne f$.

${g^{ - 1}}$ would have the same domain as f, but it's not the same function.  For example g(1)=3, thus ${g^{ - 1}}\left( 3 \right) = 1$.  But $f\left( 3 \right) = 6$.

I don't think ${g^{ - 1}}\left( {\left\{ {2,4,6} \right\}} \right)$ has really been defined. So I could guess that it means to take ${g^{ - 1}}$ of each of the elements, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

$g^{-1}$ in this case is not a *function*. It denotes the [*inverse image*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_image#Inverse_image) of g over a given set.

$g^{-1}$ is not equal to $f$. I think you're confusion was because f is defined from A to B and g is defined from B to A. But these are simply a domain and range. It says nothing about what values f and g will take. And notice that A = B = N so all that the question is saying is that f is a function that takes a natural number and outputs another natural number. And g also does the same. A and B don't say anything about what values those outputs will be.

Regarding images:

Someone above said that $f(g(3)) = f(g(\{3\}))$ which is mostly true, but the notation for your answer will have to be different. The left side is asking for a single *value* and the right-side is asking for a *set* so you will probably be expected to put curly brackets around your answer for the right side.

Ex. $f(g(3)) = f(9) = 18$ but for the right side $f(g(\{3\})) = f(\{9\}) = \{18\}$.

And also be aware that $f(g(3)) \neq f(g(\{-3,3\}))$ for example. Because the left-hand side will give you a single value, and the right-hand side will give you a *set*.

I will answer $g^{-1}(\{2,4\})$ for you to make things more clear.

So what values of $b$ can we plug into $g(b)$ to get 2, or 4?
$$g(b) = 3b = 2$$ $$\Leftrightarrow b = {2\over 3}$$
Next
$$g(b) = 3b = 4$$ $$\Leftrightarrow b = {4\over 3}$$

So you end up with the set
$$\{{2\over 3}, {4\over 3} \}$$

Now this would be the answer if we were working with rational numbers. But since the functions are defined over the natural numbers only, then you cannot have $b = \{{2\over 3}, {4\over 3}\}$ which means that your inverse image is actually **empty**.

The final answer is: 
$$g^{-1}(\{2,4\}) = \{\emptyset\}$$